# Machine Learning Python para prever gabarito de provas de múltipla escolha

Tags: python, machine-learning

Eu tenho os gabaritos dos últimos 5 concursos de uma banca examinadora. 
Gabaritos de múltipla escolha (`A`,`B`,`C`,`D`,`E`).
Vamos imaginar que a prova só tenha 5 questões, cujos gabaritos são:

```
          q1 q2 q3 q4 q5
Prova 1- (A  B  B  C  D)
Prova 2- (B  D  E  E  A)
Prova 3- (E  E  B  C  C)
Prova 4- (D  A  B  C  E)
Prova 5- (C  C  A  B  D)
```

---

Quero saber qual a probabilidade, no próximo concurso, de a `q3` ser `E`, sendo que o gabarito do próximo concurso da `q1` foi `A`, da `q2` foi `B`, `q4` foi `E` e `q5` foi `D`:

```
 q1  q2 q3 q4 q5
(A   B  ?  E  D)
```

Não encontrei nada parecido em fóruns do Brasil e do exterior.
Qual classificador devo usar em Python? Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Você pode começar a sua análise observando a [entropia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) dos dados.

Comment: Como tudo em machine learning, a resposta é: depende, vc pode usar uma série de classificadores diferentes dependendo da forma como decidir abordar o problema, minha primeira escolha seria filtragem colaborativa (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_filtering) Note que a animação é bem parecida com o que vc quer fazer. Mas perceba que se as alternativas forem aleatórias entre sim, machine learning não pode fazer muita coisa, como o amigo acima sugeriu, comece olhando a entropia dos dados para saber se exite ou não algum tipo de padrão.

Answer (score 1):

Sem saber qual foi o [PRNG](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerador_de_n%C3%BAmeros_pseudoaleat%C3%B3rios) usado pela banca para gerar as provas, vai ser muito difícil fazer esse tipo de previsão.

Em resumo, ao descobrir o PRNG usado e a sua respectiva semente, você poderá rodar o algoritmo na sua máquina e, consequentemente, determinar qual a ordem das respostas escolhidas.

Eu não acho que machine learning será muito útil no seu caso, pois a [distribuição dos números](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropia_da_informa%C3%A7%C3%A3o) dos PRNGs modernos é muito boa, ou seja, o seu algoritmo de machine learning simplesmente não conseguirá identificar um padrão e ficará apenas chutando o tempo inteiro.

Isso tudo que eu falei é partindo do pressuposto que a banca usou um computador para embaralhar as respostas. Se um humano tiver feito o embaralhamento, machine learning pode ser uma opção viável, mas:

1. Você precisará de muitos dados gerados pelo mesmo humano
2. Muito provavelmente não foi um humano